# How to Initialize Variables declared in a Class

Tags: c#, initialization

I have a sample code where I am declaring variables in a class, but when I am using them in a method, value is becoming zero.  Please find the below code further details.

```
class RectangleExample
{
   double i;
   double j;

    public void GetValues()
    {
         i = 2.5;
         j = 3.5;
    }

    public double GetArea()
    {
        return i * j;
    }

    public void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Length: {0}", i);
        Console.WriteLine("width: {0}", j);
        Console.WriteLine("Area: {0}", GetArea());
    }
}

class ExecuteRectangle
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RectangleExample obj1 = new RectangleExample();
        obj1.Display();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Please find the below code"* Can't find it ... where did you hide it?

Comment: Did you hear about constructors? :)

Comment: You never call `GetValues();` so no values are ever assigned and they remain at the default of 0. Put `obj1.GetValues();` before you call `Display();` or look at constructors.

Comment: @Ravi Kumar, could you please edit your question and add the code so that other developers can see exactly where the problem is? Thank you!

Comment: Ya when i declare constructors.....it is working fine...I want to know why it is so, please help.

Comment: @RaviKumar because when you create an object from your class `RectangleExample obj1 = new RectangleExample();` the constructor runs automatically and its purpose is initializing default values, so if you don't want to use it, then before you call the GetArea() method call the GetValues() (which will initialize your fields)

Comment: Unrelated sidenote: don't name a method `GetValue` when all it does is _setting_ some values and not _getting_ anything

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try adding getters and setters like this:
(Assuming that you are working in c# 3.5 over above)

Giving the variables a `public` property as well as setting the `get/set` properties will ensure that you have full access to the variables throughout the class and also outside of it.

I'm sure that there are better ways to solve this, but this is what i thought of:

```
class RectangleExample
{
  public double i{get;set;}=0;
  public double j{get;set;}=0;
...
...
...
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. It doesn't explain what the OP did incorrectly.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 it worked for him apparently. I'll update the answer to explain "why" shortly.

Comment: If *all* he did was convert his fields to properties, I don't see how that could be possible

Comment: You should mention that it will work only with C# 6.0+ since it's not commonly used version...

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 still dont understand why a downvote would answer that question for you. Try it out for yourself. in c# 3.5+ this works for me at least.

Comment: @Joel No, this wont work with **C# 3.5** because **there's no such version of C#**. If you meant .NET version then yes it will work but **ONLY WHEN YOU USE C# 6/0**

Comment: The point is, he never calls his inappropriately named `GetValues` method which is what sets those values. If all he does is replace the fields with properties, he still isn't setting the values. You'd have to take his OP and add in calls to setting the properties somewhere before he calls `Display` otherwise it suffers the same issue and thus, not the answer

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 if he marked this as the solution for his answer, i beg to differ. As i said, try it out for yourself, i'm nolonger getting 0 as output.

Comment: Then show how/where the values are being set. I don't see any non zero value in your post or any method invocation that would exhibit the behavior you describe. I don't need to try it, I can see it. But you're right, the comments are moot since the OP decided for some reason to select this as correct.

Comment: I think he's saying that you're declaring them as 0, and as `GetValues` is never called they don't change from 0. I assume what you've done is actually put `public double i{get;set;}=2.5;` which is not shown in your answer.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 if you debug the code with my answer, you'll see that they will get their initial values set to 0, then changed to whatever `GetValues` are set to. I don't want to get into an argument with you, however, the attitude towards me here isn't very polite. I was just trying to help.

Comment: @Joel No, the values don't change from 0. Look at this [dotnetfiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d2rhX4). Edit it to show me the values changing from 0.

Comment: You're still missing the point. Who is calling `GetValues`? Certainly not you or the OP. Equalsk does in their answer though. Properties are not the answer, they hide the error in the OP by a layer of indirectiom. However calling the actual method that sets those values *is* the answer and what is missing from both this and the OP

Comment: Okay, now i see what you are talking about when you rephrased it. I was **assuming** that he's got a "main" somewhere as nothing is called in the question, as i interpreted the question, he wanted to be able to modify the variable-values (hence the solution i provided). Hopefully we're on the same page now.

Comment: Also the statement "giving public properties will ensure you have full access to the variables throughout the class" is a bit off. He *already* has access to his fields within his class. I think you mean from *outside* his class

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 ofcourse haha, my bad. Updating it. (that's why i put it the comment there in the first place, to explain that he had access to it everywhere, based on my previous assumption)

Answer (score 5):

You never call the method `GetValues()` so no values are ever assigned to `i` or `j`. The default value for a `double` is 0.

You need to call `GetValues()` before you call `Display()`.

```
class ExecuteRectangle
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RectangleExample obj1 = new RectangleExample();
        obj1.GetValues(); // <-- HERE
        obj1.Display();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Alternatively as you've mentioned assign the values in a constructor instead.

```
public RectangleExample()
{
    i = 2.5;
    j = 3.5;
}
```

As [Thomas Schremser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959259/thomas-schremser) wisely points out in the comments the name "GetValues" is bad practice when the method does not *get* anything, perhaps "SetValues" is at least slightly better.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Display method, call `GetValues` method before the first `Console.WriteLine`

The null values are getting is beacuse you didn't initialized the variables values, the values will be initialized on `GetValues` method and you didn't called it anywhere in your code

Answer (score 0):

Every class has `constructor`. Whenever a `class` is created a `Contructor` is calling. 
If you do not provide a `constructor` for your object, **C# will create one by default that instantiates the object and sets member variables to the default values.**

your code hasn't `constructor` so your property `(i,j)` set default value (0)
you can call `GetValues` method before `Display` method or can be use my sample.

so try This

```
class RectangleExample
{
   double i  ;
   double j ;

  // class will be created calling `contructor`. Constructor will be call GetValues or set i , j values for my answer.
  RectangleExample()
  {  
     //i = 2.5;
     //j = 3.5;
     GetValues();
     //or 
     i = 2.5;
     j = 3.5;
     //GetValues();
  }
    public void GetValues()
    {
         i = 2.5;
         j = 3.5;
    }

    public  double GetArea()
    {
        return i * j;
    }

    public  void Display()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Length: {0}", i);
        Console.WriteLine("width: {0}", j);
        Console.WriteLine("Area: {0}", GetArea());

    }
}
```